# Using UILongPressGestureRecognizer on UITextField to start keyboard

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextfield

I'd like to use a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to start the keyboard, but I find that the UITextField still starts the keyboard when double tapped.

Is it possible to make `UITextField` ignore all other gestures?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a gesture recognizer won't necessarily override the standard gestures for a control, unless the standard gesture is the same as or is a subgesture of the recognizer's gesture. This implies that you can override the standard gesture by attaching a matching recognizer (e.g. UITapGestureRecognizer) and setting no action for it.